# how to write Object-oriented programming in python

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to learn pygame, p5.js is easy to write, but pygame is hard to understand cause I fail to do Object-oriented programming **Cha1.Size**, I keep getting the error:

TypeError: Pane.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Size'

don't know why it keep happening cause I think I fix the error by adding return:

def get_Size(self):
return self.Size

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *



white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)


xPos = 100
yPos = 200
#size=heigh=width
Size = 25
xSize = 200 
ySize = 200



'''
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, Size):
        pygame.init()
        self.Size = Size
    
        Cha1 = Character(25)
        Cha2 = Character(25)
'''



class Pane(object):
    def __init__(self, Size):
        pygame.init()
        
        self.Size = Size
    

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', Cha1.Size)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def get_Size(self):
        return self.Size

    def addRect(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
        pygame.display.update()

    def addText(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Hello!', True, (255,0,0)), (200, 100))
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Hello!', True, (255,0,0)), (200, 10))
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pan3 = Pane()
    Cha1 = Pane(25)
    Pan3.addRect()
    Pan3.addText()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

This is what it should be look like in p5.js as an example, but I want it to be in pygame:

```js
  var Char1 = {
  Size: 12
  };


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}


function textHere(){
  
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  textSize(Char1.Size);
  text("Hehe", 20, 70);
}


function RectHere(){
  fill(0,255, 240);
  rect(10, 30, 100,199);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  RectHere();
  textHere();
  
}
```

I can change **Cha1.Size** to **Size** but that is not **OOP**

Answer (score 0):

I see your mistake, when you are writing `Pan3 = Pane()` you forgot to put the size inside `Pane()` because when you defined that particular class you added a Size argument so whenever you have to call out `Pane()` you have to put a number which represents size.

And one more thing, if you are new to pygame or python (which im just assuming) why start with object oriented programming, I mean i do understand all your code, but you can make the same thing you are currently doing without object oriented programming which will be better to not confuse yourself.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *



white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)


xPos = 100
yPos = 200
#size=heigh=width
Size = 25
xSize = 200 
ySize = 200
Cha1 = None


'''
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, Size):
        global Cha1
        pygame.init()
        self.Size = Size
    
        Cha1 = Character(25)
        Cha2 = Character(25)
'''



class Pane(object):
    def __init__(self, Size):
        pygame.init()
        
        self.Size = Size
    

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', Cha1.Size)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill(white)
        pygame.display.update()

    def get_Size(self):
        return self.Size

    def addRect(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, black, (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
        pygame.display.update()

    def addText(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Hello!', True, (255,0,0)), (200, 100))
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Hello!', True, (255,0,0)), (200, 10))
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global Cha1
    Cha1 = Pane(25)
    Pan3 = Pane(25) #put a size value inside this
    Pan3.addRect()
    Pan3.addText()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: can you write the code cause I just got new error:
Pan3 = Pane(Size)#add Size
Cha1 = Pane(25)#name 'Cha1' is not defined.

And I don't know which one is "OOP" cause I thought "class" is OOP until you say it not OOP, so can you wrote in code on my error in class and OOP as well.

Basically "1 in class" which is I using right now and "1 in OOP".

Comment: can you explain with further details what you mean, i cant seem to understand what you mean in this comment.

Comment: simple just correct the code by write the "answer in code" - my goal are "Cha1.Size" not "Size" only similar to OOP in p5.js

Comment: please check the edit i made and hope it helps.

Comment: I check your code in VScode and not working due to error, and the reason why I use OOP cause I want to use it as a data, so later on I know which game character to change - here are the error: "NameError: name 'Cha1' is not defined" & here are the debug in VScode: "self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', Cha1.Size)"

Comment: i edited the post please check it. again.

Comment: i just realized u made a huge mistake, you are defining the variable to be Pane() and in that class you are saying Cha1, that doesnt work, you cant do that. so in my oppinion rewrite your entire script, I know it might not seem to be the perfect idea, ive done it twice and trust me from that day i have never regretted it, its better to start off fresh then to stay days not knowing one error.